# @Prompt function in Business Objects 4.1 not working

Tags: business-objects

We have migrated our universes and reports from 3.1 SP5 to 4.1 SP2. We have used derived table in one of our universe, but after the migration, Derived table parsing got failed due to @prompt function in 4.1.

We are getting parsing error while parsing the below prompts in 4.1.

```
...
(
DIM_ENC_FY.FY 
Between @prompt('Enter Fiscal Year From:','A','Fiscal Year\Fiscal Year',Mono,free,'','','') 
AND @prompt('Enter Fiscal Year To:','A','Fiscal Year\Fiscal Year',Mono,'','','','')
) 
AND
(
DIM_ENC_BFY.FY 
Between @prompt('Enter Budget Fiscal Year From:','A','Budget Fiscal Year\BFY',Mono,) 
AND @prompt('Enter Budget Fiscal Year To:','A','Budget Fiscal Year\BFY',Mono,)
)
AND
...
```

But when we gave the prompt value then we are not getting any parsing error i.e.

```
DIM_ENC_FY.FY='2013'
```

Conclusion:- We are getting the parsing error due to @prompt function of 4.1 although same prompts has been parsed in 3.1.

We have tried so many syntax but still getting the same error.

Please advice.

-Sachin

Answer (score 1):

The problem is most likely due to the empty parameters (`,'','',''`).  Try:

```
(DIM_ENC_FY.FY 
Between @prompt('Enter Fiscal Year From:','A','Fiscal Year\Fiscal Year',Mono,free) 
    AND @prompt('Enter Fiscal Year To:','A','Fiscal Year\Fiscal Year',Mono)) 
AND (DIM_ENC_BFY.FY 
Between @prompt('Enter Budget Fiscal Year From:','A','Budget Fiscal Year\BFY',Mono) 
    AND @prompt('Enter Budget Fiscal Year To:','A','Budget Fiscal Year\BFY',Mono))
```

Comment: Thanks Joe for information. We have tried but still getting the same parsing error.

Answer (score 1):

If you replace all the 'Alphanumeric' type with 'Numeric' type values in your code then it will work fine.

Example,

If you replace,

('Enter Fiscal Year From:','A','Fiscal Year\Fiscal Year',Mono,)

with

('Enter Fiscal Year From:','N','Fiscal Year\Fiscal Year',Mono,)

Then it will parse successfully.

Thanks,
P2

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Joe for information. We have tried but still getting the same parsing error. but when we have replaced @prompt with @variable then derived table got parsed successfully. Below is one of the example...                                                                  (DIM_ENC_FY.FY Between @variable('Enter Fiscal Year From:','A','Fiscal Year\Fiscal Year',Mono,) AND @variable('Enter Fiscal Year To:','A','Fiscal Year\Fiscal Year',Mono,)) AND
(DIM_ENC_BFY.FY Between @variable('Enter Budget Fiscal Year From:','A','Budget Fiscal Year\BFY',Mono,) AND @variable('Enter Budget Fiscal Year To:','A','Budget Fiscal Year\BFY',Mono,)) AND

Answer (score 0):

```
@prompt('Enter Fiscal Year From:','A','Fiscal Year\Fiscal Year',Mono,free,'','','')
```

The root problem is that BO cannot resolve 'Fiscal Year\Fiscal Year' when @prompt is used inside a derived table.
Try to change your definition to
    @prompt('Enter Fiscal Year From:','A',{'a':'b'},Mono,free,'','','')
to prove this.

Correct workaround for this issue is:
1. In Data Foundation create "parameter" and associated it with "list of values".
2. In a derived table use following syntax: @prompt(parameter).